# How do I Correlation Estimate both for a pattern and its inverse in GNU Radio?

Tags: gnuradio, symbol-timing

I'm using the [Correlation Estimator](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Correlation_Estimator) block in GNU Radio before my [Symbol Sync](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Symbol_Sync) block, in order to more quickly and reliably clock the signal.

My problem is that the data is sent as NRZ with `data[n] = 1 ^ in[n] ^ in[n-1]`, and the sync word is on the decoded data, not on the raw signal.

This means that the `01111110` repeating sync word is actually encoded as either `00000001` or `11111110` repeating, depending what bit the radio decided to start on. Both NRZ decode to `01111110`.

The correlation estimator is done before the clock sync, exactly because the clock sync is helped by the information it provides. It's a bit of catch 22: I can't do the clock sync until I've done the correlation estimation, but I can't do the correlation estimation before I have the bits (and xored them) provided by the clock sync.

What's the best way to solve this?

I could create two separate paths, one with a Correlation Estimator sync word of `00000001` and one for `11111110`, but how do I merge them? The Symbol Sync could still sync up correctly even with a mismatching Correlation Estimator, so I risk getting duplicate packets.

I could try to deduplicate the packets at the end, but how do I know that it wasn't two identical packets sent over the air? If it was, then I want two copies going out.

Example Colleration Estimator output at start of packet when preamble is "non-inverted": [image: Correlation Estimator output]

When input is inverted, correlation (in red) becomes negative.

Comment: just a side remark: `1^a^b === (!a)^b === (a==b)`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map 0 to 1 and 1 to -1 on both the reference sequence and the received bit sequence, and then correlate; an inversion will also just invert the sign.

If that mapping is hard to do on the received signal, because it's not yet decided, just use an appropriate high-pass filter: that would convert your (noisy) monopolar sighal to a bipolar one, centered around zero, and have the same effect, assuming it's overall well-balanced.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess the correlation sequence should be [-1,-1,…, 1], with -1 instead of 0. The signal is in fact -1 and +1 (well, positive and negative). But I don't understand the rest. If I invert the sync word, will the data from Correlation Estimator still help Symbol Sync, by giving phase data, saying essentially "Yeah I found the pattern at this phase, but it matches complete opposite?

Comment: well, you get a high amplitude on correlation, no matter the sign. You can do e.g. an `abs` on the signal, right, if that wouldn't work by itself (it should)

Comment: The second output on the Correlation Estimator block shows negative correlation. Are you saying Symbol Sync block will use the tags it gets on the stream from Correlation Estimator's main output even if it's high negative?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with that?

Comment: Likely I'm misunderstanding something, but isn't the point of Correlation Estimator that it sends tags that will help Symbol Sync clock better? I added a screenshot to the question. The red line (from the second output of the Correlation Estimator block) is not used directly, but will the tags still help if the correlation is negative? What requirements does Symbol Sync have on what Correlation Estimator outputs?

Comment: The correlation estimator does a complex correlation and computes a (squared) magnitude and phase of the correlation.  So an negative/inverted signal is just a phase shift of 180 degrees, but the magnitude of the correlation peak is the same, and the peak detector will behave the same, since it operates on the magnitude.

Comment: Yes, the time_est tag is emitted on the sample estimated to be the peak of a correlation with a fractional sample offset to indicate the inter-sample distance of the estimated correlation peak from the tagged sample.  The symbol sync block will use the time_est tag to reset/resync the symbol tracking PLL so that it locks in rapidly.

Comment: To get consistent results with a static detection threshold, you need to control the level of the signal going into the corr_est block with some gain control.  The symbol sync block also requires a consistent signal level (with DC offset removed), to get consistent results.

Comment: Proper symbol sync also requires "peaked" symbols, which is usually done with a matched filter ahead of the symbol sync block or using that function optionally provided by the symbol sync block

Comment: You also want to correlate against a majority of the preamble to find a good correlation peak.  Correlating against only one byte of a repeated-byte, multi-byte preamble gives you a correlation "plateau", as you keep correlating with each individual byte in the preamble, as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I now match on `([-1]*7 + [1])*10`, and get the nice plateu (like screenshot now in question, or negative plateu), and will now try to tweak pre-corr_est gains and its threshold, to get some sense of how they affect when exactly a `time_est` tag gets applied. Currently I think the main gain is that the sps "drift" (T inst/avg) resets to sps at some point shortly before the preamble. But main question has been answered, with, essentially "it already does that". I'm a bit curious why `([-1]*7 + [1])*31)` (31 repeats in signal) gives plateu and not a peak tho.